# The characters tag, good or bad?

Tags: discussion, tags

A tag has many purposes.

- The most popular tag of a question will appear in its title, which helps SEO.
- Tags help navigate the site.
- Tags have pages to describe about them, providing background on the subject.

A tag is less useful then, if it appears on most of the questions on the site.

For instance, if I ask about how Sakura is so strong, it would make more sense to have "[naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto)" as a keyword in the title, and not "[characters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters)".

Searching by the [characters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) would yield no real results.

Last but not least, there won't be a constructive, helpful tag wiki for [characters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters).

I want to hear the community's opinion about this. What do you think? Should we keep the [characters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) tag? Should we burn it to ashes?

Applying the same logic, the [character-abilities](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-abilities), [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) and [opening-songs](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening-songs) all should burn.

Comment: One more use of tags: filtering questions. Some users set favorite/ignored tags, which determines how such questions are displayed on the main page.

Comment: Indeed, which again doesn't help [tag:characters] much.

Answer (score 5):

I hadn't thought about it like that, but it makes sense.

I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/208518) where it says:

> Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories. Each tag should by itself refer to a specific category. If a tag only makes sense when used in combination with another tag (like '2005' with sql-server, 'visual' with 'studio', or '3.5' with .net), it's a bad tag.

**But in the same logic the [character-abilities](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-abilities) tag should be treated in the same way, right?**

In the same post, it is also said that:

> Tags are not for indexing your question. This isn't audio or video. Stack Overflow and Google can index your question just fine based on the text of your question itself.

And

> Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.

As far as I know, there aren't any 'characters' experts. Perhaps you can be an 'expert' in some specific series' characters, but not in characters in general.

So according to that logic: **yeah, it should be burnt to ashes!**

Comment: "character-abilities" might be useful in determining questions specifically about different character abilities versus plot explanations. I.e., I want to know more about jutsus certain shinobi use, but I'm not as interested in the plot behind it. Some what like someone asking a jQuery question would include "jquery" with "javascript"

Comment: But maybe that can be specified in-question. No?

Comment: I think it depends on how many of these types of question (as they specifically ask about the mechanics of a character's abilities) we get... (which I expect we might) if we do get a lot of them, if might help to have this tag.

Comment: I understand and agree that it allows for a better indexing system, but I am not sure if tags are supposed to do that.

Comment: I think we should wait and see how things pan out. We can use already established SEs are role models, but we shouldn't necessarily use their guidelines as if they were gospel. They may not all be suitable for our community.

Comment: The relationship between character-abilities and plot-explanation isn't the same between JavaScript and jQuery. JQuery is a library of JavaScript, it belongs to JavaScript. This tag is most similar to the arrays tag on Stack Overflow.